# Backspace not working after using jquery class

Tags: javascript, jquery

For an input field I have used a class

Here code for input field:

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->input('duration', array('class'=>'input-large text-right number-    field','value'=>'0'));
  echo $this->Form->error('duration'); 
?>
```

Here the jquery class code:

```
$(".number-field").keypress(function(e) {
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

   if(code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
     console.debug(code);
   } else {
     return false;
   }
});
```

Main reason In input field use can't type character in digits field. This class working fine.But after type digits backspace not working. For example suppose I have typed `1956`, now I want to edit it `1955`. In here I am enable to cut `6` by backspace.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/5F6YJ/

Comment: The keycode for `backspace` is `8`, you're preventing it from being pressed.

Comment: If I return true,than user can type character and digits both.Here should be type only digits.So,I think false is correct.Do you have any alternative way?

Comment: Can you suggest me,where I have to edit? @Praveen Jaganathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following script -

```
$(".number-field").keypress(function(e) {
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    //allow Backspace and Delete key.
   if((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || code == 8 || code == 46) {
     console.debug(code);
   } else {
     return false;
   }
});
```

Similar to escaping the 'backspace' key you might want to escape the 'Delete' key(code == 46)

If you just want to allow the numbers in input type then you can use HTML5 input type number.

```
<input type="number" name="year">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this:

```
var reg = /^\d+$/; // only number
$(".number-field").keypress(function(e) {
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

   if(reg.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
     console.debug(code);
   } else {
     return false;
   }
});
```